# Standalone linux version of: FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher application?

Tags: eclipse, bundles

I need to run the eclipse FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher application on a linux server. The clumsy way is to download eclipse and put it on the server but since I only need the FeaturesAndBundlesPublisher is there someway of getting that application as a standalone application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse itself is a standalone application, though it contains many applications based on different arguments.

If you're unhappy with the big size or base, you can create a .product definition, then export the ***p2.publisher*** and its dependencies as a standalone application.